# Inserting data into BigQuery table using requests library

Tags: python, google-bigquery, python-requests

Below article explains how to insert data into bigquery table using `google-cloud-bigquery` library
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-table-insert-rows#code-sample

Is there any way to insert data into bigquery table using `requests` library instead of `google-cloud-bigquery`python client library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other way you can insert data without using the **client library** is by calling the [BigQuery Rest APIs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest).

> [**insertAll**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll#http-request)
> POST:https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/datasets/datasetId/tables/tableId/insertAll

But it's advisable to use client libraries as it lets you focus on what's your requirement and what's important rather than implementing APIs from scratch and then formatting the responses into something useful.